# what preposition should be used after the verb "part"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across this sentence in a ....

> Radha parted ***with*** her mother

But it sounds weird to my ears. I think it should Rather be

> Radha parted **from**.

I was wondering which sounds grammatical to use after the verb **part**.

Comment: Could you mention where you came across the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In support of Colin Fine, both **part from** and **part with** could be used of people.

But where objects are concerned, only **part with** would be idiomatic.

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **part with someone** was the more popular phrase until the 1940s when **part from someone** shot to prominence. Since then the two phrases have changed lead several times, with **part from someone** now slightly ahead.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part+with+someone%2Cpart+from+someone